# nginx not executing basic html file

Tags: nginx

I am learning to use nginx and I was following this tutorial http://nginx.org/en/docs/beginners_guide.html. I did installed nginx successfully (at least thats what I get when I go to `localhost/index.html`). However it doesnt show the content of index.html file, also when I lookup for the errors in the log file its not logging any error. I don't know what exactly am doing wrong but here is my config file

```
user  nik;
worker_processes  1;

error_log  logs/error.log;
error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
error_log  logs/error.log  info;

pid        /usr/local/nginx/logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}

http {
        access_log      /usr/local/nginx/logs/access.log;
        error_log       /usr/local/nginx/logs/error.log;
        server{
                location / {
                        listen          80;
                        root            /data/www;
                        server_name     localhost;
                        index           index.html;
                        access_log      on;

                }
        }
}
```

P.S. my `index.html` file does present inside `/data/www`. Any help is appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I would be surprised if this server starts. You can test the configuration using `nginx -t` or for a more thorough diagnostic `nginx -T`.

Your structure is wrong, the `listen` and `server_name` directives should appear in the `server` block. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) for more.

You do not need to write `error_log` three times for the same log file - in your case `info` will also capture `notice` and more severe notifications. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/ngx_core_module.html#error_log) for details.

It is usual to start `nginx` as a daemon with the `user` set to a name normally reserved for that purpose, e.g. `www` or `nginx` (depending on which OS you are using) - but you may have good reasons to start it with your own user name.